# Popping multiple views from the navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have an application which its rootview is a menu to 4 tableviews that the user uses to set up a search query by selecting a cell that loads another subview, so the basic structure looks like this

```
Root View
- Parent View (search view)
--Sub View (user selects variables here to fill search parameters of the parent view
```

But one of the Parent View search parameters requiers another sub view to be pushed onto the navigation stack so it would look like

```
Root View
- Parent View (search view)
--Sub View (user selects variables here to fill search parameters of the parent view
---Sub View (related values to the previous subview i.e. Model / sub model)
```

I would like to know if there is a way to pop back to the Parent View from this Sub View..
I know you can pop a single view or pop back to rootview but on this occasion I want to pop two subviews... is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[UINavigationViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**popToViewController:animated:**

Pops view controllers until the specified view controller is at the top of the navigation stack.

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Use self.parentViewController.parentViewController to get grandparent viewController.

Comment: right, so I take it that this will pop ever view from the stack until it reaches the specified viewcontroller.. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

You can add a category to UINavigationController to allow multiple controllers to be popped at once.

**UINavigationController+VariablePop.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UINavigationController (VariablePop)

- (NSArray *)popViewControllers:(int)numPops animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

**UINavigationController+VariablePop.m**
    #import "UINavigationController+VariablePop.h"

```
@implementation UINavigationController (VariablePop)

- (NSArray *)popViewControllers:(int)numPops animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSMutableArray* returnedControllers = [NSMutableArray array];
    int indexToPopTo = self.viewControllers.count - numPops - 1;
    for(int i = indexToPopTo+1; i < self.viewControllers.count; i++) {
        UIViewController* controller = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
        [returnedControllers addObject:controller];
    }
    UIViewController* controllerToPopTo = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexToPopTo];
    [self popToViewController:controllerToPopTo animated:YES];
    return returnedControllers;
}

@end
```

And then from the view controller you can:

```
NSArray* poppedControllers = [self.navigationController popViewControllers:2 animated:YES];
```