# Popping back quickly not possible in a navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uikit

I have a navigation controller and it won't let me quickly pop back from a view controller onto a another view controller and to another view controller. There seems to be a delay (very small) until the back button is enabled and therefore, it requires me 2 taps to be able to navigate back one more time. Is there a way to get rid of this delay?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I am not asking for the way of popping up multiple view controllers at once. What I want is to pop one by one but it seems like for a very short period after i pop one view controller the new view controller does not register my gestures, so it wont let me tap on it to pop that new view controller as well manually. The problem just seems to be that there is a small delay until i am able to register any tap gestures onto the new view controller, it appears as it is something similar to the delayTouch or cancelsTouchInView of the gesture recognizer.

Comment: so you want to pop two viewcontrollers with one tap?

Comment: Modify your navigation controller's `viewControllers` array so that the back button takes you directly to the view controller you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popping multiple views from the navigation controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828960/popping-multiple-views-from-the-navigation-controller)

Comment: No, I don't think I was clear enough, i want to pop one by one but it seems like for a very short period after i pop one view controller the new view controller does not register my gestures, so it wont let me tap on it to pop that new view controller as well manually. The problem just seems to be that there is a small delay until i am able to register any tap gestures onto the new view controller, it appears as it is something similar to the delayTouch or cancelsTouchInView of the gesture recognizer.